# Chromedriver doesn't return a control when it's started

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using pretty old chromedriver 2.38.0.1 and cannot use any newer version since Chrome wouldn't work on it.
So when I launch a test on chromedriver 2.39.0 - 80.0.3987.1600-beta Chrome is started but it doesn't return a control. It crashes on

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Got next message in console:
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}) on port 56951
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63198/devtools/browser/96d16462-dfb4-48d0-b4f7-a9c1be000b50
[23236:20720:0905/154153.867:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[15164:21256:0905/154153.867:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(413)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -100
[15164:21256:0905/154217.733:ERROR:connection_handler_impl.cc(399)] Received message of invalid type 84

Tried it on C# and Java and in both cases have the same issue.

I have next options but don't think that I may somehow cause the problem:

```
private static ChromeOptions GetChromeOptions()
{
    String userProfile = Config.TestInputDirectory + "ChromeProfile";
    var userProfile = "ChromeProfile";
    options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=" + userProfile);
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
    options.AddArguments("--incognito");
    options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
    return options;
}
```

Google Chome version is 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (32-bit).
Note: chrome is controlled by administrator so I cannot download it manually from the official website and install.

Any suggestions what may cause it and how to fix it?

Update 1:

```
Added Result StackTrace:    
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\Users\.....\UnitTest1.cs:line 12
Result Message: 
Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54932/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
```

Update 2:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 55361
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[12716:12284:0207/124619.539:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors
[12716:12284:0207/124619.540:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors
[12716:12284:0207/124619.541:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: WelcomePageOnOSUpgradeEnabled
[12716:12284:0207/124620.242:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors
[12716:12284:0207/124620.244:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors
[12716:12284:0207/124620.244:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: WelcomePageOnOSUpgradeEnabled

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55372/devtools/browser/f0c55ef0-77be-436b-a60f-ee210dfeadf3

Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55361/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.PrepareDriver() in C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 22
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 11
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: you have to use Chromedriver v76.

Comment: I tried. None of chromedrivers higher than 2.38.0.1 don't work. I know that I have a special version of chrome because of company's policies. I have no such issue using my personal PC, 76th chromedriver works only with 76th chrome, 77th with 77th chrome, etc. But in my organisation the latest version of chrome is 76 and all previous versions of chrome work only with chromedriver <=2.38.0.1

Comment: the question is a little confusing... what version of the browser and driver are you using when you receive the exception?

Comment: Browser 76.0.3809.132, I got this exception on any version starting from 2.39.0 to 79.0.3945.132.3600

Comment: there was a buggy chromedriver release, but I don't remember if it was 76... try/catch your driver = new Chromedriver() call and post that exception.

Comment: I've added Result StackTrace since it's too long to add as comment

Comment: I've added 2nd update. It contains records from the console when I run the program as a console application

Comment: Did You tried RemoteWebDriver with "chrome" option ???

Comment: Yes, I've got the same result:

 ```Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ```